# cargar datos segun corresponda

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tengo un factory con un arreglo de datos de provincias y ciudades y lo que quiero es que según la provincia me cargue la ciudad. Esto lo hice el problema es que cuando cambia la provincia me carga los datos pero con espacios en blanco.

```
.factory('provincias',function(){
  var prov = [];
  var provincias = [
      {idProvincia:1,'nombreProvincia':'Valdivia',idRegion:1},
      {idProvincia:2,'nombreProvincia':'Del Ranco',idRegion:1},
      {idProvincia:3,'nombreProvincia':'No hay Prvincias Ingresadas',idRegion:2}

];
return{
    getProvincias: function(idRegion){
        prov = [];
        for(var i = 0;i < provincias.length; i++){

            if(provincias[i].idRegion == idRegion){
                prov[i] = provincias[i];
            }

        }
        return prov;
    }
  }
})



.factory('ciudades',function(){
var ciud = [];
  var ciudades= [
                {'id':'1','name':'Valdivia',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'2','name':'Corral',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'6','name':'Lanco',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'7','name':'Los Lagos',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'8','name':'Mafil',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'9','name':'Mariquina',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'10','name':'Panguipulli',idProvincia:1},
                {'id':'3','name':'Futrono',idProvincia:2},
                {'id':'4','name':'La Union',idProvincia:2},
                {'id':'5','name':'Lago Ranco',idProvincia:2},
                {'id':'11','name':'Rio Bueno',idProvincia:2}
  ];

    return{
        getCiudades:function(idProvincia){
            ciud = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++){
                if(idProvincia == ciudades[i].idProvincia){
                ciud[i] = ciudades[i];
                }
            }

            return ciud;

    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los espacios en blanco del arreglo es por que estas usando `prov[i] =` para guardar, `i` siempre avanza pero no siempre hay datos para guardar y esos saltos que va dando cuando la region no coincide son los espacios que ves vacios.

`prov` es un arreglo, asi que puedes usar push para meterle datos:

```
getProvincias: function(idRegion){
    prov = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < provincias.length; i++){

        if(provincias[i].idRegion == idRegion){
            prov.push(provincias[i]);
        }

    }
    return prov;
}
```

O mejor aun, usar [filter (documentacion)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

```
getProvincias: function(idRegion){
    return provincias.filter(function(provincia) {
        return provincia.idRegion == idRegion;
    });
}
```

Y aplicar lo mismo para `getCiudades`.

Comment: Vale, muchas Gracias.